# React Native navigation goes back on first click, but works the second time

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I have multiple dynamic buttons on the first screen, that should, when clicked, navigate to another screen with some parametars.

The problem is that after I add another button, navigation does not work the first time, instead it takes me to the targeted component, triggers willFocus navigation listener, runs componentDidUpdate(), but instead of rendering the targeted component I just get redirected to my original component which gets rerendered.

After that, if I click the same button, navigation works normally and the targeted component renders with all of the navigation params.

Here is my code:

```
// component with the buttons that should navigate to another component
// in render
...
<Button primary onPress={() => {
    this.onNewJobPress(item.template_id);
}}>
// event handler
onNewJobPress(template_id) {
    console.log( 'inside' ); // both console.logs are triggered
    console.log( template_id ); // id is correct
    this.props.navigation.navigate('CreateJobScreen', {
        template_id: template_id,
        new_template: false
    });
}


// targeted component
componentWillMount() {
    ...
    // adding focus listener
    this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', () => {
         // I can see both of these logs in the console before I'm
         // redirected back to the original component
         console.log('focused'); 
         console.log(this.props.navigation.getParam('template_id'));
    }
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
     // I can also see this before being redirected back
     console.log('did update');
  }
```

There are no this.props.navigation.navigate methods in the targeted component that navigate back to the first component.

Comment: Did you try passing an object to `navigate`? I've had more consistent results using that variant - `navigate({routeName: 'CreateJobScreen', params: {...}})`

Comment: Do you have a function in the targeted component that navigates back? If so, where is that supposed to be triggered?

Comment: @zaytrix There are no functions that navigate back, or to the first component.

Comment: @Kraylog I've tried your method, everything is still the same.